# ResolutionException: Cannot find candidate artifact for com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.1+

Tags: unity, google-play-services

Getting this error:

> ResolutionException: Cannot find candidate artifact for
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.1+
>   Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.DependOn (System.String group,
>   System.String artifact, System.String version)
>   GooglePlayGames.BackgroundResolution.AddDependencies () (at
>   Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/BackgroundResolution.cs:53)
>   GooglePlayGames.BackgroundResolution..cctor () (at
>   Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/BackgroundResolution.cs:45) Rethrow as
>   TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type
>   initializer for GooglePlayGames.BackgroundResolution
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor
>   (RuntimeTypeHandle type) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.cs:101)
>   UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies.ProcessEditorInitializeOnLoad
>   (System.Type type) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorAssemblies.cs:123) Rethrow
>   as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation. System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
>   System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
>   (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:519) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr,
>   System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters,
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:528) System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters)
>   (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/ConstructorInfo.cs:77)
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>   (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:372) System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:254) UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal.GetMeshProcessorVersions ()
>   (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssetPostprocessor.cs:145)
>   UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal:GetMeshProcessorVersions()

How to solve this?

Comment: I've tried that. It didn't fix the problem for me. Any other idea? Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open SDK manager and make sure you have the latest versions of following packages:

1. Extras / Android Support Repository
2. Extras / Google Repository

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: I found it here also: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr-t#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/game-engines/IckqCEZvveo